# malloc setting errno to EAGAIN

Tags: c, linux, malloc

Consider the following program:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>                                                           
#include <stdlib.h>                                                             
#include <errno.h>                                                              

int                                                                             
main()                                                                          
{                                                                              
  errno = 0;
  mlockall(MCL_FUTURE);                                           
  char *a = malloc(1);                                                      
  if (!a)                                                                       
    exit(errno);                                                                
  munlockall();                                                                 
  exit(0);                                                                      
}
```

When running as a normal user I get:

```
~ ./a.out                                                             
~ echo $?                                                             
11
```

From `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h`:

```
#define EAGAIN    11  /* Try again */
```

When running it as root or when passing `MCL_FUTURE | MCL_CURRENT` it runs successfully. I assumed either the permissions were insufficient or the flags were wrong, but neither EPERM nor EINVAL was returned.

That error is not specified in the man page of neither functions, nor in the POSIX specification for mlockall. Placing a printf after mlockall reveals that it is malloc who is setting errno.

And even more odd, malloc doesn't seem to set EAGAIN (or I'm looking in the wrong place):

```
/usr/src/glibc/glibc-2.19/malloc grep -r . -e EAGAIN
```

So what's the deal?

```
~ uname -r                                                                                                                                                                                                 18:15:04 
3.16-2-486
~ gcc --version                                                                                                                                                                                            18:15:05 
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

~ ldd --version                                                                                                                                                                                            18:15:11 
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.19-18+deb8u1) 2.19
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          18:15:15
```

Comment: You're setting `errno` to 0, calling *two* functions, and then checking the value of `errno`. You can't tell whether it was set by `mlockall` or by `malloc`. You mention adding a `printf` call, but it's not in the code you posted. You should set `errno` to 0 before each call and check it immediately after each call.

Comment: What directory is `a.out` located?

Comment: From the man page _If MCL_FUTURE has been specified, then a later system call (e.g., mmap(2), sbrk(2), malloc(3)), may fail if it would cause the number of locked bytes to exceed the permitted maximum (see below). In the same circumstances, stack growth may likewise fail: the kernel will deny stack expansion and deliver a SIGSEGV signal to the process._

Comment: Check the return value from `mlockall()`.

Comment: malloc() is not, in general, a system call.  It just calls the C runtime sub-allocator.

Comment: These days `malloc(3)` is usually implemented using `mmap(2)` to get memory from the OS.  And `mmap(2)` *is* documented as being able to set `errno` to `EAGAIN`, specifically if "too much memory has been locked".

Comment: @NateEldredge *These days malloc(3) is usually implemented using mmap(2) to get memory from the OS.*  No.  See https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.22/malloc_8c_source.html  *The price for mmap is also high now; each time glibc mmaps from the kernel, the kernel is forced to zero out the memory it gives to the application. Zeroing memory is expensive and eats a lot of cache and memory bandwidth. This has nothing to do with the efficiency of the virtual memory system, by doing mmap the kernel just has no choice but to zero.*

Comment: @AndrewHenle: But if you read on, you'll see `mmap(2)` is in fact called in many cases.  In fact, I tried running the OP's program under `strace(1)`.  What happens is that `malloc` first calls `sbrk(2)`, which fails.  It then falls back to several `mmap` calls, all of which fail with `EAGAIN`.  And this, presumably, accounts for why `errno == EAGAIN` when `malloc(3)` returns.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, `mmap` is called in many cases.  But in many cases, it's not.  Your statement *These days malloc(3) is usually implemented using mmap(2)* seemed to imply that `mmap` is used exclusively.  Also, assuming the OP is running on Linux and using glibc per the source I linked, returning `EAGAIN` on failure seems to me to violate the POSIX standard while also contradicting its own man page.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I apologize for speaking imprecisely.  I have now written an answer which explains the situation in more detail.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Regarding POSIX, I see that `ENOMEM` is the only `errno` value listed in the POSIX description of `malloc(3)`.  But [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_03.html) we see "Implementations ... may generate additional errors unless explicitly disallowed for a particular function."  So I don't think this is a POSIX violation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `mlockall()` call asks for all future memory allocations to be locked.  However, the OS sets a maximum amount of memory that can be locked by any one unprivileged process.  You can query this amount with `getrlimit(RLIMIT_MEMLOCK,...)`.  On my system it is 65536 bytes.

Now when I run your program on my system, using `strace(1)` to see what system calls are made, I get the following:

```
mlockall(MCL_FUTURE)                    = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x2318000
brk(0x2339000)                          = 0x2318000
mmap(NULL, 1048576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
mmap(NULL, 134217728, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
mmap(NULL, 67108864, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
mmap(NULL, 134217728, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
mmap(NULL, 67108864, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
exit_group(11)                          = ?
```

So `malloc` first uses `brk` to try to allocate 135168 bytes (`0x2339000-0x2318000`).  This fails because it exceeds the lock limit, and so `brk` leaves the "break point" (the top of the process's data segment) unchanged.  (See the note in the `brk(2)` man page about the differing conventions between the C library and kernel versions of `brk()`.)

`malloc` then tries instead to allocate 1048576 bytes using `mmap`.  This also fails (as it exceeds 65536 bytes), and here we see the `EAGAIN` error code being returned.  The man page for `mmap(2)` documents that `errno` is set to `EAGAIN` if "The file has been locked, or too much memory has been locked", the latter of which is exactly the case here.  `malloc`, like many library functions, will pass through the `errno` value left by system calls that it makes, so `EAGAIN` is what you see when `malloc` returns.

(The extra `mmap` calls with `PROT_NONE` seem to be intended to reserve some address space for future use, and help ensure that future allocations are aligned in an appropriate way.  See `malloc/arena.c` in the glibc source for gory details.  They fail too in this case, but that's not so relevant.)

So in short, the issue is that `malloc` tries to ask the OS for a significantly larger amount of memory than you, the user, requested.  This is for efficiency, since in most cases you are going to go on to allocate more small chunks of memory, and you don't want to make a system call for each one.  But this amount exceeds the limit for locked memory, so it fails.  `EAGAIN` is the error code set by the `mmap` system call in this case.

Perhaps the `malloc` man page should mention this possible `errno` setting, but it's pretty common that higher-level library functions don't describe all the possible ways `errno` could be set by the underlying system calls.  (For instance, `fprintf(3)` calls `write(2)`, which could set `errno` to `ENOSPC` if the disk is full, but you won't find any mention of that in the `fprintf(3)` man page.)  You're just supposed to know.

If you want to use `mlockall(MCL_FUTURE)`, then you probably can't plan to allocate memory using `malloc(3)`.  You'll have to get it manually from `sbrk(2)` or `mmap(2)`, and of course, plan to keep it under the appropriate limit or fail gracefully.  This is pretty inconvenient and restrictive, so if you have a need for some locked memory, and you're not root, you probably want to just use `mlock(2)` on sufficiently small objects instead.

Comment: Actually, C99 says explicitly (7.5): _The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard_ - in other words, `errno` can be set arbitrarily by a standard library function as long as the standard imposes no specific requirements, which it does not in the case of `fprintf` or `malloc` among many others. I'm sure more modern variations of the standard have the same or similar wording.

Comment: @davmac: Indeed, and as I commented above, likewise [POSIX (2.3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_03.html) says: "Implementations shall not generate a different error number from the ones described here for error conditions described in this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, but may generate additional errors unless explicitly disallowed for a particular function."

Answer (score 0):

> 1. `mlockall` is setting error number, reason Some or all of the specified address range could not be locked.
> 2. Standard `malloc()` does not set errno to EAGAIN on failure.

Man Page

[mlockall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlockall)

[malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)

Answer (score 0):

What's the return value from `mlockall()`?

Per [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/mlockall.html):

> [EAGAIN]
>
> Some or all of the memory identified by the operation could not be locked when the call was made.

Per the [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html):

> ```
>    EAGAIN Some or all of the specified address range could not be
>           locked.
> ```

Comment: As I noted above, at least in my tests, `mlockall()` actually succeeds, and doesn't set `errno` at all.  The OP didn't explain it very clearly, but in fact it is `malloc` (or rather `mmap`, which it calls) that sets `errno = EAGAIN`.